# How to prevent the clipped content inside a container with borderRadius to not overlap the border on each corner

Tags: flutter

I made a container that supposed to show a picture with a colored border around it, with the addition borderRadius I set it to 8, but then I notice when I set the container to clip the content, it makes the border corner fade like the following:

[image: Content overlap border corner]

Here's how I wrote it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
            ),
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want the content not to overlap the border I have, how to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I want the content not to overlap the border I have, how to do that?

To achieve this, you'll need to set the `foregroundDecoration` and `decoration` properties of the `Container`, the difference between the two is that,`foregroundDecoration` will paint the decoration **in front** of the child and `decoration` will paint **behind** the child, that is why you get the clipping when just using `decoration`

**Note**: Setting `foregroundDecoration` with a `clipBehavior` will trigger an `AssertionError` as `clipBehavior` must be specfied with a `decoration`

Updating your code to the following, to get the desired effect:

```
Center(
  child: Container(
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
    ),
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    child: Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image: Preview of foregroundDecoration on a container]